# Parsing 2 Files Line-By-Line and need to avoid Duplicates (in special cases)

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, duplicates, name-collision

I have 2 files that I'm parsing line-by-line adding the information to 2 separate `ArrayList<String>` containers. I'm trying to create a final container "`finalPNList`" that reflects the 'Resulting File/ArrayList' below.

Issue is that I'm not successfully avoiding duplicates. I've changed the code various ways without success. Sometimes I restrict the condition too much, and avoid all duplicates, and sometimes I leave it too loose and include all duplicates. I can't seem to find the conditions to make it just right.

Here is the code so far -- in this case, seeing the contents of `processLine()` ins't truly relevant, just know that you're getting a map with 2 `ArrayLists<String>`

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> masterList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
public static List<String> finalPNList = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> modifier = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> skipped = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Entry<String, String> e : tab1.entrySet()) {
    String key = e.getKey();
    String val = e.getValue();

    // returns BufferedReader to start line processing
    inputStream = getFileHandle(val);
    // builds masterList containing all data
    masterList.put(key, processLine(inputStream));
}
for (Entry<String, List<String>> e : masterList.entrySet()) {
    String key = e.getKey();
    List<String> val = e.getValue();
    System.out.println(modifier.size());
    for (String s : val) {
        if (modifier.size() == 0)
            finalPNList.add(s);
        if (!modifier.isEmpty() && finalPNList.contains(s)
                && !modifier.contains(key)) {
            // s has been added by parent process so SKIP!
            skipped.add(s);
        } else
            finalPNList.add(s);    
    }    
    modifier.add(key);
}
```

Here is what the data may look like (extremely simplified dealing with about 20K lines about 10K lines in each file):

File A

> ```
> 123;data
> 123;data
> 456,data
> ```

File B

> ```
> 123;data
> 789,data
> 789,data
> ```

Resulting File/ArrayList

> ```
> 123;data
> 123;data
> 789,data
> 789,data
> ```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The output I expect is in the resulting file section of my post... The last piece

Comment: Would you please explain in a bit more detail the rules of how you wish to handle duplicates? It's not yet clear from the above example.

Comment: @Meesh sorry about not being too clear. That is the meat of the puzzle--In essence, all the data from file A should make it to the output file, however, data from file B, should only be added, if it doesn't already exists (provided by file A). If it exists, add it to an "exists" ArrayList for review...I account for this but end up removing too much. I can add some examples to my thread, but I'd like to keep it reduced to avoid clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `!modifier.contains(key)` is always true, it can be removed from your if-statement.
- `modifier.size() == 0` can be replaced with `modifier.isEmpty()`.
- Since you seem to want to add duplicates from File B, you need to check File A, not `finalPNList` when checking for existence (I just checked the applicable list in `masterList`, feel free to change this to something more appropriate / efficient).
- You need to have an `else` after your first if-statement, otherwise you're adding items from File A twice.
- I assumed you just missed `456` in your output, otherwise I might not quite understand.

Modified code with your file-IO replaced with something that's more in the spirit of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
masterList.put("A", Arrays.asList("123","123","456"));
masterList.put("B", Arrays.asList("123","789","789"));
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : masterList.entrySet()) {
    String key = e.getKey();
    List<String> val = e.getValue();
    System.out.println(modifier.size());
    for (String s : val) {
        if (modifier.isEmpty())
            finalPNList.add(s);
        else if (!modifier.isEmpty() && masterList.get("A").contains(s)) {
            // s has been added by parent process so SKIP!
            skipped.add(s);
        } else
            finalPNList.add(s);    
    }    
    modifier.add(key);
}
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/mOVG8B).

Comment: I'll give it a go in a few minutes and let you know if it worked--thank you for your time and effort. Be sure I'll be back to confirm if this did the trick.

Comment: This line made all the difference: "&& masterList.get("A").contains(s)" Thanks for your time and effort!